# why getting wrong left and top position value from draggable jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i get left and top postion of div but i getting wrong value when top going to negative value then the result showing is wrong. and same as left. what is i do wrong this code.

```js
$('#mega-game').draggable(
    {
        drag: function(){
            var offset = $(this).offset();
            var xPos = offset.left;
            var yPos = offset.top;
            $('#mega-p-x').text('x: ' + xPos);
            $('#mega-p-y').text('y: ' + yPos);
            $('.man').css('top', yPos + 'px');
            $('.man').css('left', xPos + 'px');
        }
    });
```

```css
#mega-game {
    width: 6em;
    height: 6em;
    padding: 0.5em;
    border: 3px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 0 1em 1em 1em;
}
.man{
width: 2em;
height: 2em;
background:red;
position:relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="mega-game">
    <ul>
        <li id="mega-p-x"></li>
        <li id="mega-p-y"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="man"></div>
```

Comment: anyone idea what wrong in this code.

Comment: What's wrong with values? You get a negative ones, as they should been.

Comment: they not get exact position value.

Comment: The values look just like expected. Could you please specify, what you expect?

Comment: see my code again i updated what i want , when mega-game div is move then same time man div move automatically. how this is possible its not run on my site this is same code is on my site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess `.offset()` method get position of the element with a little delay or `drag` event is triggered before position is changed. You should take position values from arguments of `drag` callback. Check out fixed code snippet:

```js
$('#mega-game').draggable(
    {
        drag: function(e, ui){
            var offset = $(this).offset();
            var xPos = ui.position.left;
            var yPos = ui.position.top;
            $('#mega-p-x').text('x: ' + xPos);
            $('#mega-p-y').text('y: ' + yPos);
            $('.man').css('top', yPos + 'px');
            $('.man').css('left', xPos + 'px');
        }
    });
```

```css
#mega-game {
    width: 6em;
    height: 6em;
    padding: 0.5em;
    border: 3px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 0 1em 1em 1em;
}
.man{
width: 2em;
height: 2em;
background:red;
position:relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="mega-game">
    <ul>
        <li id="mega-p-x"></li>
        <li id="mega-p-y"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="man"></div>
```